# log in history in safe mode: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: osx-yosemite

What command can I use in terminal to see login history if someone created a hidden account or booted the machine in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

`last` command from the Terminal

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-find-user-login-history.405237/